# Loading million records into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load 90 million records into a MySQL table. I tried using mysqlimport but it just returns a response like nothing was done (there are 11 fields).

> mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by='\t' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --ignore-lines=1 --user=admin --password --columns=field1,field2,field11 main e:\master.utf8

<Returns: main.master: Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

So then I went into myphpadmin and did:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'e:\master.utf8'
INTO TABLE master
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES (field1, field2, ...field11);
```

But after a few minutes I get:

> Error in processing request
> Error code: 500
> Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
> It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.

Then if I try to access the data from myphpadmin, I now get the same error. I cannot even get a list of tables. It seems phpmyadmin cannot handle the amount of data and jams-up.

When I try to access the database and table from the WorkBench, I get in, but when I do a count, I get an error.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master;<br>
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "few minutes" -- Perhaps exactly 300 seconds?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';`